# Access parent from iframe even though domains don't match?

Tags: javascript, dns

I have a javascript script that is being run from within an iframe that is trying to access the parent but I'm getting the following error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL mysite.com from frame with URL myothersite.com?. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The iframe html is on a different domain but I didn't think that would matter. This is the code that is generating the JS error:

```
var parent_site = parent.document;
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You're not allowed to do this for security reasons.  google 'XSS vulnerability'

Comment: No, there is no way to access the parent window if it’s from another domain unless you have control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent domain is a trailing part of the iframe domain (i.e., iframe is child.parent.com and parent is parent.com) you can set the domain of the iframe document with `document.domain = "parent.com"` and avoid the problem.

If the domains of the parent and the iframe are unrelated there is no way to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Do some research on CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing): http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

You essentially need to add this to your .htaccess of the parent domain:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers x-requested-with
```

Ideally you'd replace the `*` with the domain(s) for which you want to allow access.